# How to give separate log file only jar file package logs

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

get a logger instance named "`com.foo`"

```
   Logger  logger = Logger.getLogger("com.foo");
```

Now set its level. Normally you do not need to set the level of a logger programmatically. This is usually done in configuration files.

```
logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
```

Comment: I have custom jar file.it having log4j.xml file. I have written one application .it used that jar. those logs getting into application logs.  i want separate file for  jar file having logs.

Comment: where is the question??

Answer (score 0):

```
 this is an example of log4j2 configuration 

<Configuration status="WARN">
      <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
          <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <Appender type="File" name="File" path="location/to/logging/space/file.txt">
        <Layout type="PatternLayout" pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Appender>
      </Appenders>
      <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.foo" level="trace" additivity="false">
          <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="error">
          <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
      </Loggers>
    </Configuration>
```